# Structuring Nav Menu and Background Custom page (Help)

Tags: menus, themes, walker, custom-background

i´m creating theme is my first theme and i have a problem with  panel nav menu of wordpress, I´m creating the order of nav menu in the panel wordpress and does not order, i was make page and automatically the page add to nav menu, i need delete a page of menu and doesnt not eliminate.

this is my header.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php language_attributes () ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset = "<?php bloginfo ('charset');?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php wp_title (); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body class="<?php body_class(); ?>">
    <div id="app-yahcrea" class="app-yahcrea">
        <!-- Comienza el menu -->
        <header class="header-yahcrea">

            <div class="content-header-yahcrea">
                <div id="menu-icon" class="menu-icon">
                    <span class="icon-menu"></span>
                    <span class="icon-menu"></span>
                    <span class="icon-menu"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-mobile" id="menu-mobile">

                    <nav class="mobile-nav-yahcrea">

                        <?php 
                        wp_nav_menu(array(
                            'container' => true,
                            'items_wrap' => '<ul id="menu-top">%3$</ul>',
                            'theme_location' => 'Primary',
                            'walker' => new Walker_Nav_Menu

                        ));
                    ?>
                    </nav>

                </div>

                <div class="logo-yahcrea">  <?php 
                $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
                    $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );
                    if ( has_custom_logo() ) {
                        the_custom_logo();
                    } else {
                            echo '<a href="'.home_url().'"><img width="64" height="64"src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . './assets/images/PerfilFblanco.png' .'"></a>';
                    }
               ?></div>
                <nav class="nav-yahcrea">    

                    <?php 
                    if(has_nav_menu('primary')){
                        wp_nav_menu(
                            array(
                                'theme_location' => 'Primary',
                                'container' => 'div',
                                'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                                'container_id' => 'navbarSupportedContent',
                                'items_wrap' => '<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">%3$s</ul>',
                                'menu_class' => 'nav-item',
                                'echo' => true,
                                'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', // en caso de que el menu no exista cargar wp_page_menu
                                'before' => '', // texto antes del texto del enlace.
                                'after' => '', // texto despues del texto del enlace.
                                'link_before' => '<span>', // <a href=""><span> ....
                                'link_after' => '</span>', // </span></a>
                                'item_spacing' => 'preserve', // preserve / discard
                                'depth' => 2, // numero de niveles que serán mostrados
                                'walker' => '' 

                            )
                        );

                    }
                        ?>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </header>
```

Functions.php, i want add the walker class but, I don't know what it's for that, if add the order menu or dont...

```
function yahcreatheme(){
        register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'primary' => __('Primary Menu', 'Yahcrea Theme'),
                'secondary' => __('Secondary Menu', 'Yahcrea Theme')
            )
        );
}
```

How can i add in my theme custom background for each page?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by add theme custom background, can you explain it in different words and be more specific? Are you sure that you set your nav menu to appear in the primary location?

Comment: Mmm, what do you mean about appear in the primary location? in the panel of wordpress   i´m indicated the primary location. And about custom background, if, how i can add in the panel of wordpress in appearence edit the background of theme?.